# Append or prepend opening/closing tags with jQuery

Tags: jquery, append, prepend

I'm trying to wrap replies in a comment stream in a  like this:

```
$('li.comment').next('li.replycomment').append('<ul class="thread">');
$('li.replycomment').next('li.comment').prepend('</ul>');
```

It doesn't work unfortunately. If I do the following it works no problem:

```
 $('li.comment').next('li.replycomment').append('<ul class="thread"><li>awesome</li></ul>');
    $('li.replycomment').next('li.comment').prepend('<ul><li>radical</li></ul>');
```

Is there a reason jQuery won't let me insert an unclosed tag?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want:

```
$('li.comment').next('li.replycomment').wrap('<ul class="thread"></ul>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it's invalid HTML. Try using [wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) instead.